# $\{-n+\frac{1}{n};n\in\mathbb{N}\}=M$ closed in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Why is $\{-n+\frac{1}{n};n\in\mathbb{N}\}=M$ closed in $\mathbb{R}$ (here is $\mathbb{R}$ endowed with the standard topology? 
I could use the criterion: Is $(x_n)\subseteq M$ such that $x_n\to x_0\in\mathbb{R} \Rightarrow x_0\in M$.
I started with: Let $(x_n)\subseteq M$ such that $x_n\to x_0\in\mathbb{R}$ For every $n\in \mathbb{N}$ there exists $k_n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n=-k_n+\frac{1}{k_n}$. Now it is $x_n=-k_n+\frac{1}{k_n}\to x_0$. Why is $x_0\in M$?

Answer (score 2):

If you notice that each of these points is isolated, you could observe that this set is the complement of the set

$$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (-(n+1)+\frac{1}{(n+1)},-n+\frac{1}{n}) \cup (0,\infty)$$

Which is an infinite union of open sets and therefore open (and whose complement is closed).

Answer (score 2):

A set is closed if and only if it contains all of its limit points. Your set has no limit points, so it's trivially closed by that criteria.

To explicitly show that your set has no limit points, note that for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, the open set $(x-1/2,x+1/2)$ contains at most one point in $M$ since distance between successive points of $M$ is
$$\left(-n + \frac{1}{n}\right) - \left(-n-1 + \frac{1}{n+1}\right) = 1 + \frac{1}{n(n+1)} > 1.$$

Answer (score 1):

In fact you will be able to prove that if $\lim\limits_{n \to +\infty} -k_n + \frac{1}{k_n}$ converges to a real $x_0$ then $(k_n)$ has to be eventually constant. Hence $x_0 \in M$ as was supposed to be proven.

Another way to prove the result is to prove that the complement of $M$ is open as mentionned in the other response.

Answer (score 0):

Let $m,n \in \mathbb N$. Suppose $n \not = m$ and WLOG say $m > n$. Then note that $$|(-n + \frac{1}{n}) - (-m + \frac{1}{m})| = |m - n + \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{m}| \geq |m - n| \geq 1$$

This shows that the absolute difference of non-identical terms in the sequence is at least 1. It follows easily from this fact that any $(x_n) \subseteq M$ which converges is constant after some rank, and thus converges in $M$.